# Google Maps API clickable marker reveal more info

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google maps api i've created a simple map  for my site that displays several points all at once.  But i'd also like to make each of these points clickable so that on click they reveal a very brief description.

my javscript to plot the points is below, can anybody who has managed this offer any advice?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    // create a closure for your latitude/longitude pair
    (function(coord) {
        // set the location...
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coord[0], coord[1]);
        // ...and add the Marker to your map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            draggable: true,
            map: map
        });
    })(coords[i]);
};
```

Comment: You need to use an [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows), which you bind to your markers

Answer (score -1):

Just replace `(function(coord)` by `(function(coord[i])`

Comment: map failed to load after doing this

Comment: Did you take a look at error console ? Which line is a problem ?